# Search for a string/pattern in selected text in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to decrypt the selected text if the string "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" occurs in the selected text.
I have the following code but it doesn't show up anything.

```
#!/bin/bash
xsel > pgp.txt
if [grep -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt]
then
gnome-terminal --command "gpg -d -o decrypted.txt pgp.txt"
gedit decrypted.txt
fi
```

When I run it on terminal after selecting a text it says

```
line 3: [grep: command not found
```

I'm new to bash scripting. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: There should be a whitespace between `[` and `grep`. In addition you should test `grep`output against something.

Answer (score 4):

Confusingly, `[` is actually a program, it is also know as [test (1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test).  You do not need to enclose your grep command in a `[`. If you were going to use `[` for something you need to seperate the left bracket with a space character `[ foo == bar ]`

The if syntax is: `help if`

```
if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi

The `if COMMANDS' list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, then the
`then COMMANDS' list is executed.
```

The command you want is probalby more like this.

```
if grep -q -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt; then
   ...
   ...
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be a space after [.
And grep returns strings so your test could fail.
You better check exit status of grep.

```
grep -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt
exitcode=$?
if [ $exitcode ]
then
   # not found
else
   # found 
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`[` is a command, not a syntax. It's equivalent to the `test` command.

Remove the square brackets to see if it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsel > pgp.txt
if grep -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt
then
    gnome-terminal --command "gpg -d -o decrypted.txt pgp.txt"
    gedit decrypted.txt
fi
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Insert a space after the left bracket also doesn't work in your case:

```
if [ grep -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt ]
then
```

because bash expands it as:

```
if test grep -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt
then
```

and you'll get the `line 3: [: too many arguments` error.

Remember that `[` is a command. It takes arguments and procedures an exit code.

You can also discard the standard output of the `grep` by using:

```
if grep -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt >/dev/null
then
```